# how to sort card view in recycler view in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardview

I have some API response as below:

```
 [      
        {
            accountType: a,
            accountId: 1,
            accountStatus: active,
            isDefault: false,
            accountName: texas1
        }, {
            accountType: b,
            accountId: 1,
            accountStatus: active,
            isDefault: false,
            accountName: texas2
        }, {
            accountType: c,
            accountId: 1,
            accountStatus: active,
            isDefault: true,
            accountName: texas4
        }, {
            accountType: a,
            accountId: 1,
            accountStatus: active,
            isDefault: false,
            accountName: texas5
        }, {
            accountType: b,
            accountId: 1,
            accountStatus: active,
            isDefault: false,
            accountName: texas6
        },
        {
            accountType: a,
            accountId: 1,
            accountStatus: active,
            isDefault: false,
            accountName: texas7
        }, {
            accountType: b,
            accountId: 1,
            accountStatus: active,
            isDefault: false,
            accountName: texas9
        }  ]
```

I want the `isDefault` true account to be shown as first `cardview` with `accountType` as `c` then account type sorting should be done like account type a and its all account list and the account type `b` and all its account list. over all my card should like this

- account type `c`
- below default card
- then account type `a`
- all cards
- then account type `b`
- all cards

I always want `isDefault` card to be on top irrespective of its account type then I want to sort `cardView` based on `accountType` as a,b,c etc.
I m displaying account type then `cardView` below in `xml` layout
How to achieve this on `Bindview`? any help is appreciated

Answer (score -1):

The `RecyclerView` will display elements in the exact order that you pass them to your adapter. What you need to do is to rearrange your elements in the order you want them to be in and then pass them to the adapter so that they can be shown. A simple example based on your input

```java
//This is just a data class for our API response
class Account {
    String accountType;
    int accountId;
    boolean accountStatus;
    boolean isDefault;
    String accountName;
}

//Lets say that you have your API response in a list as such
List<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<>();
accountList.add(/*Response from API*/);

//Now we create a sorted list based on your rules
List<Account> sortedAccountList = new ArrayList<>();

//First we need the isDefault account
for (Account account : accountList) {
    if (account.isDefault) {
        sortedAccountList.add(account);
        accountList.remove(account);
        break;
    }
}

//Now we add all 'c' type accounts
for (Account account : accountList) {
    if (account.accountType.equals("c")) {
        sortedAccountList.add(account);
        accountList.remove(account);
    }
}

//Do the same as above for the other account types. You can also apply more rules as per your needs.
```